# Is there a simple way to replace a character at any arbitrary position in a string in Java (and get new String)?

Tags: java, string

I know of no easy way to do this. Suppose I have the following string-

```
"abcdefgh"
```

I want to get a string by replacing the third character 'c' with 'x'.

The long way out is this -

```
s1 = substring before third character = "ab" in this case
s2 = new character = "x" in this case
s3 = substring after third character = "defgh" in this case
finalString = s1 + s2 + s3
```

Is there a simpler way? There should be some function like

```
public String replace(int pos, char replacement)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`StringBuilder#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abcdefgh");
sb.replace(2, 3, "x");
String output = sb.toString();
```

http://ideone.com/Tg5ut

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the `String` to a `char[]` and then replace the character. Then convert the `char[]` back to a `String`.

```
String s = "asdf";
char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
arr[0] = 'b';
s = new String(arr);
```

Comment: @CodeBlue any particular reason why not? I was going to edit a similar suggestion into my answer (until I saw this answer).

Comment: @MattBall, won't this be slow and memory consuming for large strings?

Comment: @CodeBlue you can't do much better in Java, since strings are immutable.

Comment: I am dealing with strings of size 10KB or more

Comment: Doesn't matter. Any solution that modifies a `String` must create a copy of it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no simpler way than to concatenate the pieces.

Comment: Right, just move all of this in some function `replaceCharAt` and forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a StringBuilder instead [StringBuilder Java Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since every String is basically just a char[] anyway, you could just grab it and manipulate the individual chars that way.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
String crap = "crap";
String replaced = crap.replace(crap.charAt(index), newchar);
```

but this will replace all instances of that character

Comment: This is not C#. This code won't compile for at least 2 reasons.

Comment: try lowercasing the word replace

Comment: `'` is for characters not for Strings

Comment: and actually thinking to add in the variables

Comment: @Alex noted - that was a typo. but it has nothing to do with the language. everything here is valid

Comment: Since you edited yes, but at first it was not, as shown by Matt Ball.

Comment: I mean, it was a dummy variable anyway. This was not intended to be copy and pasted into his source, resulting in a beautifully working final result. It was an answer to his question, and a valid one at that. And @MattBall was *technically* correct about it not compiling, but I mean..duh? It's an unfinished code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Try the `String.replace(Char oldChar, Char newChar)` method or use a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score -2):

```
String yourString = "abcdef"
String newString = yourString.replaceAll("c" , "x");
System.out.println("This is the replaced String: " + newString);
```

---

This is the replaced String: abxdef

Comment: No! That's not what I am looking for.

Comment: If the input is instead `"abcdecf"` the output will be `"abxdexf"` when it should be `"abxdecf"`. -1

Comment: also, replaceAll is intended to take a regex as the first argument. So technically this will work, but it still isn't quite right